# Timestamp transform to date

Tags: java, rest, linkedin-api

I work on java app which works with LinkedIn REST api. Api returns creationsTimestamp as number. My question is how to transform it into regular date. Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is a milliseconds since the epoch timestamp? Simply use the  [appropriate method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-).

Answer (score 0):

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
  Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
  System.out.println(date);
```